# Rails4 using ajax and jquery to display a date using strftime in format %m/%d/%yyyy leads to division

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, ruby-on-rails-4, strftime

I have an ajax call that looks up a date in the database. The date is stored as a double in the database. I then convert it to a string and use Date.parse to convert it to a date. From there, I use strftime to format it. My problem is that when I use jquery to update the view, something along the way is interpreting / as divison so I end up with a decimal that is the result of the month divided by the day divided by the year.

Here is my js.erb

```
$('#debug').html(<%= @sdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")%>)
```

When I remove the / and just have "%m%d%Y" it displays correctly. Also, I tried moving the formating to my controller and outputting the result to the console. The console displays the correct output, but the view is still doing division. It seems to be how jquery is interpreting the code. Can anyone tell me how to get it to display properly in the view? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes, string need quotes :)

```
$('#debug').html('<%= @sdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")%>');
```

Or use `.to_json` method:

```
$('#debug').html(<%= @sdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").to_json %>);
```

Comment: lol i spent over an hour trying to every combination of escape_javascript, raw, etc. Right after I posted this question I thought of the quotes as well. Thanks for the quick response!